# Moment.js - time elapsed with local timezone and UNIX input

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working with an API that returns dates in UNIX format: i.e. **1441647410**.

With the following moment.js helper, I am able to convert it to a more readable format (**05/22/15, 09:33**):

```
UI.registerHelper('formatUnix', function(context, options) {
  if(context)
    return moment.unix(context).format('MM/DD/YY, hh:mm');
});
```

Instead of displaying an absolute time, I'd like to display time elapsed from now (i.e. 5 hrs ago, or 11 weeks ago) in this example.  How could I do that?  I am trying to define now with `moment()`, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
UI.registerHelper('fromNow', function(context, options) {
  if(context)
    var now = moment();
    var diff = now - context;
    return moment.unix(diff).format('hh');
});
```

How can I should an amount of time elapsed from now (11 weeks ago) instead of an absolute time (5/22/15)?  Also, is there any way for the browser to automatically grab the client's local time?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about parsing unix into moment time and then using [from](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/):

```
return moment(context).from(moment());
```

Comment: yup `return moment.unix(context).from(moment());` will do the trick. as the staples button would say, that was easy... thank you @kravits88

Comment: Will this account for the user's local time zone?

Comment: @pingo no problem, please mark as answer if this has solved your problem. In regards to localization I would suggest looking at http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/ if you are not using moment-timezone already. You can then convert from server(UTC?) time into users local time.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just need to use the [`fromNow()` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) after constructing the moment instance using `moment.unix()`:

```
moment.unix(context).fromNow()
```